# jQuery cannot make .click to work on this code

Tags: jquery, css, animation, click, ready

i have the following problem:

i want the animation to start on click instaed of on ready ... it works when it is set on .ready but no when on .click

```
$('div.main').ready(function() {
  setTimeout("$('div#tl').css({'top' : '-175px', 'left' : '-175px'})", 100);
  setTimeout("$('div#t').css({'top' : '-175px'})", 300);
  setTimeout("$('div#tr').css({'top' : '-175px', 'left' : '325px'})", 500);
  setTimeout("$('div#r').css({'left' : '325px'})", 700);
  setTimeout("$('div#br').css({'top' : '325px', 'left' : '325px'})", 900);
  setTimeout("$('div#b').css({'top' : '325px'})", 1100);
  setTimeout("$('div#bl').css({'top' : '325px', 'left' : '-175px'})", 1300);
  setTimeout("$('div#l').css({'left' : '-175px'})", 1500);
});
```

here is the HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub" id="tl"></div>
    <div class="sub" id="t"></div>
    <div class="sub" id="tr"></div>
    <div class="sub" id="r"></div>
    <div class="sub" id="br"></div>
    <div class="sub" id="b"></div>
    <div class="sub" id="bl"></div>
    <div class="sub" id="l"></div>
</div>
```

and here the CSS:

```
div.main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

div.sub {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Please pass functions to `setTimeout`, not strings (although that should not be the problem here). And apparently you haven't fully understood what the `ready` event handler is for. Please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196) and the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery). What you want to do (setting up a click handler) is very well explained there.

Comment: the css  method `top:50%` will not work on a relative positiond element

Comment: @YusafKhaliq it does work :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include them within the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div.main').click(function() {
  setTimeout("$('div#tl').css({'top' : '-175px', 'left' : '-175px'})", 100);
  setTimeout("$('div#t').css({'top' : '-175px'})", 300);
  setTimeout("$('div#tr').css({'top' : '-175px', 'left' : '325px'})", 500);
  setTimeout("$('div#r').css({'left' : '325px'})", 700);
  setTimeout("$('div#br').css({'top' : '325px', 'left' : '325px'})", 900);
  setTimeout("$('div#b').css({'top' : '325px'})", 1100);
  setTimeout("$('div#bl').css({'top' : '325px', 'left' : '-175px'})", 1300);
  setTimeout("$('div#l').css({'left' : '-175px'})", 1500);
});
    });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fARb4/1/)

Comment: no probs ;) don't want to take credit just for fixing up a bit of css

Comment: You should really pass functions to `setTimeout` instead of strings though. `eval` is evil!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put your code in a dom ready function

```
$(function() {
 $('div.main').click(function() {
   setTimeout("$('div#tl').css({'top' : '-175px', 'left' : '-175px'})", 100);
   setTimeout("$('div#t').css({'top' : '-175px'})", 300);
   setTimeout("$('div#tr').css({'top' : '-175px', 'left' : '325px'})", 500);
   setTimeout("$('div#r').css({'left' : '325px'})", 700);
   setTimeout("$('div#br').css({'top' : '325px', 'left' : '325px'})", 900);
   setTimeout("$('div#b').css({'top' : '325px'})", 1100);
   setTimeout("$('div#bl').css({'top' : '325px', 'left' : '-175px'})", 1300);
   setTimeout("$('div#l').css({'left' : '-175px'})", 1500);
 });
});
```

The problem is that your div does not exist when the js is executed. The dom ready function is called when all the elements are ready.

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/